# Is there a way to change the object the this keyword refers to?

Tags: java, oop, this

I was wondering if there was a way to do what it says in the title. As an example I have code below:

```
public List<Shape> path() {
    List<Shape> path = new ArrayList<Shape>();
    path.add(0, this);
    while (this.parent != null) {
        path.add(0, this.parent);
        this = this.parent;
    }
    return path;
}
```

I want to find a legal way of doing `this = this.parent` so that I can keep adding the `parents` to the arraylist until there are no more parents. Is it possible?

Thanks.

Comment: Why don't you use a local variable instead of `this`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, it's not possible. `this` is bound to the current object, but nobody stops you from using other reference names like `currentNode` or whatever that you first initialize as `this` (`currentNode = this`) and then assign the parents to it: `currentNode = currentNode.parent`.

Answer (score 2):

You can change the state of the object which is referred by `this` ,

But you can't make `this` point to some other object,

`this` is `final`

For your case you can create a local reference and operate on it

Answer (score 1):

Assing `this` to variable of the correct type before the `while` and use that variable.

```
public List<Shape> path() {
    List<Shape> path = new ArrayList<Shape>();
    path.add(0, this);

    SomeVar node = this;

    while (node.parent != null) {
      path.add(0, node.parent);
      node = node.parent;
    }
   return path;
}
```